# Substitute measure of integration

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, conditional-probability

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathcal{X}$ and $Y:\Omega \rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$  random variables. Let $f:\mathcal{Y}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function. Moreover there exists a regular conditional distribution such that:
$$\mathbb{P}_Y(E)=\int_{\mathcal{X}} \mathbb{P}_{Y|X=x}(E)\mathbb{P}_X(dx)$$

Now let us consider the following integral:
$$ \int_{\mathcal{Y}}f(y)\mathbb{P}_Y(dy).$$

My question is, if I can "plug in" the first equation into the second to get something like:
$$\int_{\mathcal{Y}}f(y) \int_{\mathcal{X}} \mathbb{P}_{Y|X=x}(dy)\mathbb{P}_X(dx)$$

If this is allowed which integration has to be done first and how could I proof that statement? Or are there any books where this statement is proven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct is:
$$\mathbb{E}[f(Y)]=\int_{\mathcal{Y}}f(y)d\mathbb{P}_Y=\int_{\mathcal{X}}d\mathbb{P}_X\int_{\mathcal{Y}}f(y)d\mathbb{P}_{Y/X}$$
The demonstration is easy:
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\int_{\mathcal{Y}}f(y)d\mathbb{P}_{Y/X}=\mathbb{E}[f(Y)\mid X] & \hspace{20pt}\text{(Doob 1953, Theorem 9.1)}\\ 
\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}[f(Y)\mid X]\right]=\mathbb{E}[f(Y)] & \hspace{20pt}\text{(Definition of Conditional Expectation)}
\end{array}$$
More general:
$$\mathbb{E}[f(X,Y)]=\int_{\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}}f(x,y)d\mathbb{P}_{X\circ Y}=\int_{\mathcal{X}}d\mathbb{P}_X\int_{\mathcal{Y}}f(x,y)d\mathbb{P}_{Y/X}$$

Comment: Hi can you maybe provide another source instead of Doobs book as I dont own it?

Comment: Any book on regular conditional probability.

Comment: @guest1 see Theorem 4.1.16 in Durrett, Probability: Theory and Examples